# How do I deal w/ question with bounty already given (as thanks for time & effort) but still unsolved?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, bounty

In my question thread [Why does "nw_add_textures_for_principled" work w/ Existing Material but not w/ dynamically created ones?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267380/why-does-nw-add-textures-for-principled-work-w-existing-material-but-not-w-d) I have put a `+100 bounty` and received some useful fixes for the override problem from **@Marty Fouts** but these changes did not resolve the issue described in the thread's question. We couldn't figure it out but since I want to reward his time and effort and the bounty was to expire today, I decided to give the bounty to him as a huge thank you but cannot mark his post as an answer. Unfortunately, it is still an issue, the code only works when interactively executed in the *Python Console* but **we** found out for some reason it does not work when executed in the *Text Editor*. I desparately need an answer and I'm wondering how to go about this. Can I raise another bounty on this question like `+500` or should i create a new question for this? The title would still be exactly the same but seem as if it was a duplicate question. How do I deal with this situation?

Comment: Doesn't the answer you got from the devs work when run and from the console?  If so, what's different about the new question you would ask?

Comment: oh i asked the question before i got the ansewer from the dev. its resolved now :)

Comment: Would you mind if I updated my answer's script to incorporate what the devs told you, with attribution, of course?

Comment: sure pls do! il mark it as the correct answer then.

Comment: Sorry I spelled your name wrong in the answer. Particularly embarrassing because I strongly believe in calling people what they want to be called. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very versed in bounties myself, never given or received any.

You can read more about bounties in the [Bounties help page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

If you do not manually award the bounty to any answer yourself, there are a few fallback defaults and the system will automatically award it to an answer posted after the bounty started. Generally the highest scoring answer posted after the bounty was started, or the accepted answer if any.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
> the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
> minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
> amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible
> answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
> is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
> awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question
> owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the
> bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty
> owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty
> amount at the time of bounty expiration.

If non of the answers satisfy your needs and you never accept one the system will still award the bounty or part of it to the highest score answer after the grace period, even if you don't manually, so your "thanks" would be guaranteed.

After that period you can start a new bounty on your question if non of the answers solved your problem. The minimum amount of points for the new bounty will be double the previous bounty minimum.

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the
> minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on
> the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and
> so on).

Posting a new question is also an option, but only if it is significantly different from the current one. If you can rephrase it to be a distinct question then go for it, if it will still read like the same one, then awarding a new bounty will be the best course of action.

Comment: alright thank you very much for your answer! :)